# Apply CSS class depending on directory location

Tags: javascript, css

I have built a simple CSS drop down menu. What I am looking for is a way to add a css style class to the menu span depending on what directory you are in.

For example, you are in the contact directory http://www.site.org/contact on any page in that directory I would like the contact menu item which is a span with an id name to stay the color assigned to .current. Then if you leave to go to the about directory the contact dismisses the .current style and about changes to .current.

Comment: Is this a static site? How is the menu being built? Are you using ASP, PHP, or some other language?

Comment: this can be done easily at server side. at server side you always know which directory or url is in process. so you can append the css class on menu span according to url/directory

Comment: That link doesn't work for me...

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - It's just an example URL

Comment: @Brent Friar it is ASP on an IIS server in a custom CMS. Menu is created as a widget that you plug into the CSS.

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - Thank you. I have to use an example link because of the private organization I work with. The site is only open to certain 'Donors'

Comment: cdeszaq's solution will work, but you could make some changes to the code that builds the menu. It's a matter of adding a CSS class to the current menu, or even the current menu and the parent if you have multiple levels of menus. Then you could incorporate all of the CSS in to a couple of lines in the main stylesheet. It would be much easier to administer in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is to treat the CSS like it is a theme. The way this is done for a "theme per directory" sort of approach is to have a base-line set of styles that will always apply to the site, and then also have a style sheet within each directory that overrides the base styles to change the theme for that directory.

So, for example, if you put this on all pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

you are saying that `base.css` (in the root directory of the site) will define most of the styles, but then `theme.css` will be looked for in the same directory of the current page, and the styles there will *also* apply to the page, allowing you to override the base styles with different colors, etc.

If you have a dynamic site, you should be able to add a class to the navigation element that should be active currently. If it is static, however, or you cannot add/remove classes, you could give each navigation element a unique ID and use that ID in the various `theme.css` files to apply styles to the appropriate nav item within that directory.

Things will get a bit tricky if you go deeper underneath a particular directory, but the solution there is to either duplicate the theme file in that directory (yuck), or to have the deeper HTML pages link up to the correct directory like this (example for 1 directory lower):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../theme.css">
```

Comment: That is probably the easiest way to do it. I did not even think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is something like this (JavaScript):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className += ' ' + 
  window.location.path.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\//g, '-');
```

Then you can have style rules like:

```
body.content .menu { color: green; }
```

or whatever. You'd run the code sometime after the `<body>` tag is there but before the DOM is ready so as to avoid a "flash of unstyled content" (or, in this case, a "flash of mis-styled content").

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have something like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="nav-menu1">...</li>
  <li id="nav-menu2">...</li>
  <li id="nav-about">...</li>
  <li id="nav-contact">...</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var whichCurrent = 'nav-' + window.location.href.replace('http://www.site.org/', '');
document.getElementById(whichCurrent).className = 'current';
```

Then in your menu Javascript you add and remove the `current` class according to your spec.